# Having plus or minus in front of a number in expression

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2012, reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0

I'm using Report Builder 3.0.  I have a report which needs to display figures with a plus or minus in front and also requires the font to change colour based on the plus or minus

This is the output of the query

```
fiscal     total    sdg Difference
2014/2015   2341    SDG  NULL
2015/2016   2378    SDG  +37
2016/2017   2323    SDG  -55
2017/2018   2352    SDG  +29
2018/2019   2576    SDG  +224
2019/2020   1451    SDG  -1125
```

This is my expression in a textbox

```
=sum(IIF(Fields!sdg.value="SDG",cint(Fields!Difference.value), 0),"SDG_Difference")
```

Because I'm summing I have to change the 'Difference' field to integer so I lose the '+' and '-' in my report

I've tried adding a little text box in front of the textbox with the 'Difference' expression (highlighted in yellow)

[image]

This is the code in that textbox to produce the '+' and '-'

```
=IIF(Reportitems!Textbox1.value >0 ,"+", "")
```

Although this isn't ideal I can live with it - my problem comes though when I want to colour the font - Green for '+' and red for '-'

```
=IIF(ReportItems!textbox1.value = "+" ,"LightGreen","IndianRed")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why have you changed the case of 'Textbox1'?  it seems to be what the message is telling you not to do

do you require

```
=IIF(ReportItems!Textbox1.value >=0,"LightGreen","IndianRed")
```